# Using maps in offline mode

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, google-maps-api-2, offline-caching

I'm starting developing a project of an android app.
For this project i need a map where i can draw circles, polylines and polygons and click in all of this draw shapes  to show informations about each one. At this point, googlemaps + spatialite or googlemaps + quadtree + utils to identify if a LatLng belongs to a circle/polyline/polygon can solve the problem but i have one more requirement: i need to cache a zone of the map to work with it on the street without internet. I know that google maps official app can do this with th typing of "Ok Maps" but there are anyway to use that cache in  my application? There are another way to do a cache of the map before going to the street and go without internet?

Preferably i would like to use google maps but I'll have to use another api? What?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the need for Google to check your api key, I have not seen any way for third party apps to access google maps offline.  If you need offline capabilities, one of the main solutions is something called osmdroid which has a similar interface to google maps but you can cache tiles for offline use.

[OSMDroid](https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/)

Comment: maybe i can cache the tiles of googlemaps ore use another tileprovider or not?

Comment: As soon as you try to make any calls to the Google maps API it will try to verify your api key.  Without a network it can't do that so I believe it will fail to load tiles.  You need to use a different library for offline maps.

Comment: Thanks for your help Kaediil. You're right. Is the OSMDroid the best choice? Do you know other alternatives? I also know that exists mapsforg and nutiteq